# How can I make NodeJS's console.log always print output within a single line no matter what?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to format the JSON logged through `console.log` in the terminal?

I'm logging a lot of debug data and if the the logged data exceeds a certain length, the terminal logs it prettified in many lines. I'd like to change it to log in one line, no matter the length of the data. Is there any way to do that?

In summary, I want to change this log style:

```
[12:34:56][DEBUG][CODE] - {
  data: {
    action: 'action',
    url: '/path/to/my/api?variableOne=valueOne&variableTwo=valueTwo'
  }
}
```

To this log style:

```
[12:34:56][DEBUG][CODE] - { data: { action: 'action', url: '/path/to/my/api?variableOne=valueOne&variableTwo=valueTwo' } }
```

Comment: Related question I just found that asks specifically about arrays only: [node console.log() output array in one line](/q/51573010).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to format the JSON logged through console.log in the terminal?

Yes there is. Create a custom console object. See [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#new-consoleoptions) for how to do that and what options you can specify. In particular, see also the [`inspectOptions` docs](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-showhidden-depth-colors).

The particular `inspectOptions` option you are looking for are `breaklength` and `compact`:

> `breakLength`: `<integer>` The length at which input values are split across multiple lines. Set to Infinity to format the input as a single line (in combination with `compact` set to `true` or any number >= `1`). **Default**: `80`.
>
> `compact`: `<boolean>` | `<integer>` Setting this to `false` causes each object key to be displayed on a new line. It will break on new lines in text that is longer than `breakLength`. If set to a number, the most `n` inner elements are united on a single line as long as all properties fit into `breakLength`. Short array elements are also grouped together. For more information, see the example below. **Default**: `3`.

So since you asked

> I'd like to change it to log in one line, no matter the length of the data

Then you probably want to do something like this:

```js
const { Console } = require('node:console')
console = new Console({
  stdout: process.stdout,
  stderr: process.stderr,
  // ignoreErrors, colorMode, groupIndentation
  inspectOptions: {
    // ...
    breakLength: Infinity,
    compact: true,
    // ...
  }
});
```

And then you can test it with `console.log({a:1,b:2,c:3,hello:"world!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"});`.

You can also just use [the `util.inspect` function](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#utilinspectobject-showhidden-depth-colors) on specific objects you want to make a formatted string for, and then do `console.log` on the default global `console` object, passing the returned string.